# How to display URL in the address bar in lowercase only?

Tags: firefox

I am using Firefox 55.0.3 (64-bit).

Many websites use a mixture of uppercase and lowercase in their addresses. [While this may be important for a server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13511227/url-structure-lower-case-vs-upper-case), this is not important for me. In fact, this bothers me.

Is there a way to force Firefox to display the address bar in lowercase only?

Take, for example, the subreddit "Windows 10". Firefox displays its URL in the address bar as the following:

```
https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/
```

Note the uppercase "W" in "Windows10".

I want Firefox to behave in a way that, in the background, it is still using the correct uppercase letters where applicable, whereas what is displayed in the address bar uses lowercase only.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. I am specifically confused by the example you provided

Comment: @Ramhound: To me the question is clear - he wants to see "moviesforyoutowatch.com/batman-vii-the-dark-knight-whatevers" instead of "MoviesForYouToWatch.com/Batman-VII-The-Dark-Knight-Whatevers", see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33489532/6404709

Comment: `https://SuperUser.com/Questions/1253924/How-to-Force-Firefox-to-Display-the-Address-Bar-in-Lowercase-Only` - `https://superuser.com/questions/1253924/how-to-force-firefox-to-display-the-address-bar-in-lowercase-only` is one example.

Comment: @user598527 Thank you. I have nonetheless added an example for what I would like to do here.

Comment: @Ramhound How does this have anything to do with SEO? This can be done by sneaking in something like `address.toLowerCase();`. Whatever capitalization is actually going on still goes on in the _background_ - I just don't want to _see_ it. If this can be done in `about:config` then that's even better. If I need to modify the source code and recompile, the so be it.

Comment: @Ramhound Plus, just because I understand a question doesn't mean I have the answer to it.

Comment: @Ramhound I was attempting to defend user598527 from your "So answer the question if it is clear". Feel free to take this matter to meta. I'm pretty sure that administrators have access to IP addresses and all those incriminating evidence.

Comment: @Ramhound: I don't know the answer. I understood the question, but I can't answer. I admit that the question was unclear due to absence of the term "URL".

Comment: @user775075 Forget it.  There isn’t any need to defend anyone against a stock comment. Nobody needs defending

Comment: You're asking the browser to lie to you. No browser will help you do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, what you're asking is not practical (see my **update** below for a workaround).

Many servers use case insensitive file paths, yes, but a tiny minority still use case-sensitive file names and file paths.

In other words, if you were to do such a thing and you ran into a 404 page not found because the website required a capitalized letter somewhere in its path, there would be no way for you to troubleshoot the problem.

By the way, the example url you cited is a bad example, because even if you were to write: https://www.reddit.com/r/windows10/

Instead of giving you a 404, that url would still redirect to the correct one.

**UPDATE:**

My advice would be to hide the standard url bar manually through the menu and to create your own [separate bar](https://linuxbox.co.uk/firefox_extension_tutorial.php) for displaying the url in the particular way you want to.

I am suggesting doing it this way to minimize the side-effects of messing with the main url bar, which may be used programmatically by other scripts. Also, having two bars, one on top of each other when not hidden, will make it easier for you to create the extension, and also troubleshoot the extension should anything go wrong when you stumble on to an edge case.

Comment: There may have been an understanding (ie. my question was perhaps not clear enough). I want Firefox to behave in a way that, in the _background_, it is still using the correct uppercase letters where applicable, whereas _what is displayed in the address bar_ uses lowercase only.

Comment: @Stephan_Branczyk Thank you for your explanation. Now I understand what you mean. However, such cases do not occur on a sufficient basis for me to consider them. I'm guessing such cases may occur if I was to manually type in a rather long web address, which is not something I do.

Comment: @Stephan_Branczyk I have seen your detailed update and I shall accept this as an answer. Thank you.

Comment: Also, you could just wait until you're able to implement that solution, or until someone else gives you a more complete answer. For instance, I did not vet that tutorial I linked you to yet. It doesn't have a date on it, and for all I know it could be out of date. In any case, feel free to change the accepted answer at a later date if someone else comes up with a better answer.

Comment: @Stephan_Branczyk Understood. Please forgive my rashness. I am quite new to this platform (Stack Exchange).